I cant access anything in "Audio Content Creation", error "You don't have operation permissions"
I just created a speech service, but when I go to "Audio Content Creation", I can't do anything (New - Upload - Export)

I tried to add myself as owner role, and other roles, but still, I can't do anything in Audio Content Creation

As mentioned in this MS Document, generic roles like Owner and Contributor won't have data plane permissions to work with Speech resource and gives no access errors.
Initially, I too got same error when I go to "Audio Content Creation" with Owner access on it:

To resolve the error, you need to assign roles containing Speech in their names. In my case, I assigned "Cognitive Services Speech User" role to the user under Speech service like this:


Note that, there will be delay of 5-6 hrs. after assigning the role to initialize the operation.

When I checked the same after few hrs., I'm able to create new files successfully in "Audio Content Creation" like this:

Reference:
Azure AI - You don't have operation permission  - Microsoft Q&A by santhoshkc

When I created the service, I added a lot of roles, including "Cognitive Services Speech Contributor" but didn't work.
When I opened it now, it works !! as you quoted "there will be delay of 5-6 hrs".
I wish your answer existed when I created the service, thank you.
